# Documentation on iterating through a hierarchical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe with hierarchical columns like so:

```
>>> site
DeviceType            Meter         Inverter                   \
DK                    18757            20178            20179   
Field            Generation     Inverter_Gen     Inverter_Gen   
App_Field  generation_cumul generation_cumul generation_cumul   
2014-01-01              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-02              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-03              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-04              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-05              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-06              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-07              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-08              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-09              NaN              NaN              NaN   
2014-01-10              NaN              NaN              NaN   

DeviceType                         Weather                       
DK                    20180          20653                       
Field          Inverter_Gen     Irradiance             CellTemp  
App_Field  generation_cumul irradiance_avg cell_temperature_avg  
2014-01-01              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-02              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-03              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-04              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-05              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-06              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-07              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-08              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-09              NaN            NaN                  NaN  
2014-01-10              NaN            NaN                  NaN  

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

Where can I find documentation on iterating through columns at a given level.  For instance, if I want to iterate through each 'DK'.  I suppose that would be iterating through sub-arrays, but is it doable in a simple manner?

Comment: You can [groupby an index level](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#groupby-with-multiindex): `site.groupby(level='DK', axis=1)`, and then iterate through that like a normal groupby object. It may be cleaner to use and `apply` after grouping, instead of iterating over the groups.

Comment: Thank you Tom, this is helpful.  If I do `site.groupby(level='DK', axis=1)`, I can then iterate through each group.  `for name, group in grouped:
 print(name)
 print(group)` What I'm left wondering though is how I can get a handle on the columns fields below DK.  How, for example can I access the "App_Field" headings in each 'DK' group?